# Redirect URL's with example.com/blog?p=1234 to wordpress default URL (example.com/blog/actual-url-of-post) doesn't work in Safari

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, redirect

I have a website and WordPress blog on **example.com** and **example.com/blog/** respectively. I serve the latest blog to my website through an API in which contains post title and post ID, with which I form URL **example.com/blog/?p=1234**.
 Everything works fine on every browser (**example.com/blog/?p=1234** redirects to **example.com/blog/actual-url-of-post**) except safari in iOS and mac, and chrome on iOS, with error 414 with url example.com/blog/actual-url-of-post/,%20example.com/blog/actual-url-of-post/,%20example.com/blog/actual-url-of-post/,%20example.com/blog/actual-url-of-post[**very long string reapeating ,%20example.com/blog/actual-url-of-post/**] [[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2RCC.png)

I have seen people getting error **414 Request-URI Too Large** because of the server configuration which doesn't allow long URL. But in my case, it is happening only in some specific broswer. Any guidance will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: is it getting repeated - beacause as long as you stay under 2000 chars, it should work on any browser

Comment: also, can you show the code, on how you are redirecting?

Comment: @Stender yes the string ',%20example.com/blog/actual-url-of-post/' is repeating multiple times and the length exceeds the max URL length acceptable to the server. Also, I am not controlling the redirection part, WordPress itself does the redirection, which is working fine in chrome and firefox. The problem is in safari.

Answer (score 0):

These links might solve your issue:

https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203370

Comment: These links only guide on how to handle redirection, but in my case, WordPress is doing the redirection part, and the redirected URL is bad when the request is from safari.